# CNTK handwriting recognition

Tags: python-3.x, cntk, handwriting-recognition

Has anyone ever programmed using CNTK for reading hand-filled documents? I tried OCRs and they dont do handwriting recognition at all (next to nothing). Thinking of using CNTK for the same. I searched and found that not many have tried such a thing. Any advice on libraries or any pointers anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a basic OCR example using CNTK:

https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/master/Tutorials/CNTK_103B_MNIST_FeedForwardNetwork.ipynb

However, in order to use the model in a real application you will need a way to segment the handwritting.

Comment: In addition to the MNIST OCR which is an elementary introduction to CNTK. You will find examples for segmentation examples with R-CNN (https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/Object-Detection-using-Fast-R-CNN) and you can look into recurrence based networks (LSTMs: tutorial number: CNTK 106, CNTK 202 and CNTK 204) for additional ideas to combine networks.

Comment: Thanks Emad. The training is going well. If I do crack the segmentation method I shall add as an edit.